# Windows 10, cmd, schtasks, varying arguments

Tags: scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments

Let's say that a given scheduled task simply runs a batch script (*.bat or *.cmd).

Is it possible to pass varying command line arguments to such script?

With "varying", I mean, the arguments change from one call to the next; and, thus, I do not want to hardcode values in the properties of the scheduled task itself.

What I envisioned is something like this:

```
schtasks /run /tn \myapps\mytask <arg1> <arg2>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The only way I can think of is for the batch file to read it's arguments from another file...

Comment: Yeah, I do have that in mind; but I figured I asked. Also, I am afraid of consecutive calls and racing condition, say, calls 3 and 4, where the "another file" now contains arguments for call 4 right before task 3 is launched ?  I am just speculating, here.